# How to process org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset with apache beam?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, apache-beam

I want to process the data from org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset Object that I am retrieving from spark.sql(" query ") with Apache beam.
But I am not able to apply PTransform to this Dataset directly. Right now I am using a solution in which I dump the Dataset to txt file and then process it with beam.
Is there any way in which I can consume Dataset / JavaRDD directly into the beam (Ptransform)?

I am using apache beam 2.9.0.

Comment: When you say dump the dataset to txt file, are you saying you dump the data into a file, and let Beam read the data from the file to further process?

Comment: @Rui Wang Yes that is how I am doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge you cannot consume Dataset into Beam now. Dataset is Spark's API that it's coupled with Spark internal implementations. So you cannot start Spark job, run until a step, and then let Beam takes it over.

Your approach is the right approach to connect two different system's pipeline. Even for pipelines of the same type system, data sharing usually is the only way to connect different pipelines.

There is one possibility to make Spark on Beam work, which is automatically generate Beam code from Spark code. It does not exist in open source world, but you can read some information from LinkedIn's practice: https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2019/01/bridging-offline-and-nearline-computations-with-apache-calcite